# How do I transfer logins from 2008R2 to 2014 with passwords?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, sql-server-2014

I've tried `Tasks`>`Generate Scripts...` and set 'Script Logins' in the Advanced Scripting Options, but I get this in the output:

```
/* For security reasons the login is created disabled and with a random password. */
```

Is there a simple way to script these logins with passwords or another way to transfer logins from a 2008R2 instance to a 2014 instance?

Comment: http://www.sqlsoldier.com/wp/sqlserver/transferring-logins-to-a-database-mirror (just ignore the mirroring references - this works for moving any logins between any instances).

Comment: @Aaron that looks very nice at first glance, thanks.

Comment: @Aaron I ended up using [this](http://tomaslind.net/2014/02/11/copy-logins-sql-server-instances/) which is basically the same thing. Thanks for pointing me in the right direction.

Answer (score 9):

In order to transfer logins, you will need to use the [sp_help_revlogin](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/918992) script and procedure.  This will allow you to transfer logins and retain the password from on instance to another.

Comment: I've been to that page but I evidently don't understand it. Method 3 says "Create a log in script that has a blank password", so presumably that isn't it?

Comment: @JackDouglas Not sure what that phrase means, but you just need to create those two stored procedures on the source server and, in the end, just execute sp_help_revlogin, take its output from SSMS and execute it on the new server. You'll have your logins recreated with the correct pwds.

Comment: i have tested this on SQL 2014 but does not work, the same method works till sql 2012. also mentioned in http://support.microsoft.com/kb/91899

Comment: I tested `sp_help_revlogin` but it does not work in SQL 2014 SP1 CU1(12.0.4416). [This KB article](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/918992) mentions that it works until SQL Server 2012.

Answer (score 7):

I can't wait for everyone to learn about this:

https://dbatools.io/

https://blog.netnerds.net/2016/06/its-2016-why-is-sp_help_revlogin-a-thing/

In short: install the dbatools Powershell scripts.

You now have a wonderful set of commands that can not only copy SQL users, passwords, permissions, etc; but also an exhaustive set of commands for copying databases, jobs, even whole instances :D

Example usage:

```
Copy-DbaLogin -Source sqlsvr2000 -Destination newsql2016
```

or:

```
Export-DbaLogin -SqlServer sql2005 -FileName C:\temp\sql2005-logins.sql
```

Cheers!

Answer (score 2):

you can still use sp_help_revlogin script and procedure for SQL 2014 as answered earlier ([How to transfer logins and passwords between instances of SQL Server](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/918992)). But it needs manual modifications (enlarging length of hash value variables):

- replace 256 -> 512
- replace 514 -> 1028
- replace 1024 -> 2048

Answer (score 0):

Yes you Can through Powershell using various Modules:

**1- Using DBATools: Open Powershell**

```
<# Install-Module dbatools#> #only if not installed

<# Load the module#>

Import-module dbatools

export-dbalogin -SqlInstance ServerName f:\floginsdba.txt
```

**2- Using SQLSERVER Module:**

```
<# Install-Module sqlserver#> #only if not installed

<# Load the module#>

Import-module sqlserver

cd sqlserver:\serverA\default\logins   # replace the default with any named Inst

dir | %{$_.script()}                   

<# For security, it will create disabled  logins and hashed passwords for sql logins.#>
```

Let me know if you need any help.